# F# Saturn Framework: what is the difference between 'get' and 'forward'?

Tags: f#, saturn-framework

for example, the following code inside a router computation exppression

```
get "/time" (warbler (fun _ -> System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") |> sprintf "Time now is %s" |> text))
```

seems to have exactly the same effect as

```
forward "/time" (warbler (fun _ -> System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") |> sprintf "Time now is %s" |> text))
```

In both cases, the current time is displayed whenever a client navigates to `/time`.

In what situations will these be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can supply any `HttpHandler` to `forward`, so it doesn't surprise me that you see this behavior.  Where `forward` becomes really useful is for nesting entire sub-`routers` under a certain path root.  In this case, forward makes sure that the routes under the child path match only on the sub-portions of the route.

For example, take this setup:

```
let routerA = router {
 get "/foo" (text "hi")
}

let routerB = router {
 forward "/hi" routerA
}
```

In this case, the full path to the routerA get method would be `/hi/foo`, not `/foo`.